# Native javascript class not being exported in scalajs

Tags: scala.js

In ScalaJS 1.2.0, having defined the following class:

```
@js.native
@JSGlobal
class ButtonProps(val title: String) extends js.Object
```

I expected that `val props = new ButtonProps("foo")` would create a javascript instance (according to [the doc](https://www.scala-js.org/doc/interoperability/facade-types.html)).

But instead I get `ButtonProps is not defined`. Any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you defined `ButtonProps`, with `@js.native @JSGlobal`, is telling Scala.js that it should *not* define `ButtonProps` itself, and that instead it should get `ButtonProps` from the JavaScript global scope. This only makes sense if some JavaScript code (e.g., in a library) actually defines that class.

If you meant to define `ButtongProps` yourself in the Scala.js code, then you should remove `@js.native @JSGlobal` and only keep

```scala
class ButtonProps(title: String) extends js.Object
```

Comment: Indeed it works. I also needed to add `val` otherwise no accessor was created in Javascript.